# video stalling, audio fine (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: graphics, 18.04, video

When streaming video on Chrome, the image frequently but irregularly (about once every other minute) stalls for several seconds, while the audio keeps playing perfectly. The Internet connection is fine. After a couple of seconds, it resumes. When I move the mouse during a stall, the video instantly resumes.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
- Gnome 3.28.1
- Chrome 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Dell Vostro 5568 15 FHD
- Resolution 1920x1080

How should I proceed to diagnose the problem?

---

Active processes according to `htop` when video stalls:
[image: <code>htop</code> screenshot]

Comment: One thing to try is to update your kernel with `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`, then reboot. If that doesn't help, another thing to try is to turn off hardware acceleration in Chrome's advanced settings, then restart Chrome. If that doesn't help, turn hardware acceleration back on and restart Chrome, and then check CPU usage in `top` or something like it while the video hang is happening to see if something is using a lot of processing power. If that doesn't help, `iotop` might reveal something using a lot of IO at that time, freezing the system.

Comment: All suggestions tried, no success. Screenshot added that shows processes and cpu-usage when playing a youtube-video.

Comment: Added another screenshot that catches a stalling moment. Doesn't look like cpu-overload to me, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like that. It also doesn't look like [they're being blocked on IO](https://peteris.rocks/blog/htop/#process-state).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Weirdly, i retried turning off the hardware acceleration and the videos run smoothly now. Feel free to submit an answer and I'll gladly accept that one as solution -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not an ideal solution, turning off hardware acceleration in the browser (Chrome) fixed the issue.